# Retrieve sources using shell command or globbing, update build accordingly

Tags: cmake, glob

How can I get a CMake generated build system to retrieve source files using an arbitrary shell command and update the build properly?

The motivation for doing this is to migrate from another build system to CMake. The intermediate goal is to have a single list of source files shared between the build systems. The list of source files might actually live inside of the other build system but in general suppose some shell command can retrieve the list of source files. This problem is very similar to the problem of using globbing to get source file names but in this case manually listing all the source files in a `CMakeLists.txt` file is not a reasonable alternative.

Even if there's no way to get CMake itself to do this, an answer that provides any automated solution would be fine (e.g. a script that wraps the generated build system).

---

**Very simple concrete example of the problem**

We have an app that consists of two source files, `main.cpp` and `foo.cpp`. For some reason it is desirable to acquire the names of sources files with some shell command instead of listing them in a `CMakeLists.txt` file. For this example, the files are listed one per line in `files.txt` and we `cat` this file. In general, the shell command is some script that retrieves a list of source files in mysterious ways.

main.cpp (ver 1)

```
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void foo();

#endif
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl;
}
```

files.txt (ver 1)

```
main.cpp
foo.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)
project(SourcesFromCommand)

# run some external command that retrieves our source files
execute_process(COMMAND cat ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/files.txt OUTPUT_VARIABLE files)
# turn newline separated relative filenames into cmake list of absolute filenames
string(REPLACE "\n" ";${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/" file_list ${files})

# print filenames to make sure the list came out right
foreach(file ${file_list})
    message(${file})
endforeach()

add_executable(main ${file_list})
```

CMake generates a working build system for a project that consists of the above files. Later, our app is successful and popular so we decide to add new functionality for ver. 2.0. `main.cpp` now calls `bar()` which lives in `bar.h` and `bar.cpp`. We update `files.txt` accordingly.

main.cpp (ver 2)

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main() {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

void bar();

#endif
```

bar.cpp

```
#include "bar.h"

#include <iostream>

void bar() {
    std::cout << "bar()" << std::endl;
}
```

files.txt (ver 2)

```
main.cpp
foo.cpp
bar.cpp
```

The build system previously generated by CMake no longer works -- trying to use it results in linker errors because it doesn't know about `bar.cpp`. This can be solved manually by touching the `CMakeLists.txt` file or rerunning the `cmake` command but the point of a build system is to free us from such arduous and easily forgotten manual labor. How can this be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with a makefile that `touch`s the relevant `CMakeLists.txt` files.

I'll continue from the OP's example and also add a directory, `glob_us/` from which we want to glob all filenames matching `*.cpp`. It contains `baz.cpp` which is similar to the OP's `bar.cpp`.

Relevant files:

- Makefile
- CMakeLists.txt
- files.txt
- main.cpp
- main.h
- foo.cpp
- foo.h
- bar.cpp
- bar.h
- glob_us/baz.h
- glob_us/baz.cpp

The bottom of `CMakeLists.txt` becomes:

```
file(GLOB globbed_files glob_us/*.cpp)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glob_us)

add_executable(main ${file_list} ${globbed_files})
```

`Makefile` contains the following:

```
MAKEFILE_DIR := $(shell dirname $(realpath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

GLOBBED := $(wildcard $(MAKEFILE_DIR)/glob_us/*cpp)

# phony target that depends on whatever files we need to touch
cmake: $(MAKEFILE_DIR)/CMakeLists.txt

$(MAKEFILE_DIR)/CMakeLists.txt: $(MAKEFILE_DIR)/files.txt $(GLOBBED)
    @touch $(MAKEFILE_DIR)/CMakeLists.txt

.PHONY: cmake
```

Generate a build system:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G $MY_FAVORITE_GENERATOR ..
```

Then build:

```
make -f ../Makefile && $MY_FAVORITE_BUILD_SYSTEM_COMMAND
```

Files can be added to and globbed from `glob_us` or as in the OP's example, to `files.txt`, without manual intervention.